# How to save/update data using resource without http request in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have the data with me. I want to save to model using the resource.

I tried this, but getting error:

```
r = MyResource()
bundle = r.build_bundle(request=request, data=data)
r.save(bundle)
```

It is not working. Can you help me here ?

Comment: please share some proper code snippet, for better understanding and getting early answered for your question.

Comment: When you want to update an object, you have to send patch request to http://example.com/api/v1/resource/id right ? But I am getting the data from different place, so I have the data with me and I want to save it to db. I think I can save it to db directly without resource. But authorization is already written for resource so want to save using resource.

Comment: `bundle = r.build_bundle(request=request, data=data)` here what is in  request and data please add that object information.